# Colorize sides regular polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-shape, polygon

To illustrate what [edge-coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring) is, I'd like to colorize a regular polygon.  I want to generate the shape using TikZ, then colorize the sides (edges) of the polygon separately, for instance by doing something like this:

```
\draw[red] (polygon.side 1);
```

Unfortunately, the world does not seem to work like this.  For now my ugly workaround is to overdraw using dotted, dashed, and thick lines.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, dotted, minimum size=2cm, regular polygon,
  regular polygon sides=5] (polygon) {};
  \draw[thick] (polygon.corner 1) -- (polygon.corner 2);
  \draw[dashed] (polygon.corner 2) -- (polygon.corner 3);
  \draw[thick] (polygon.corner 4) -- (polygon.corner 5);
  \draw[dashed] (polygon.corner 5) -- (polygon.corner 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: edge-colored pentagon]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to use a node?

Comment: I want the simplest thing possible.  I may have driven into the wrong direction.  Also, why wouldn't I want a node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `regular polygon colors` option, there's no need for extra commands to draw the sides. Everything is done within the node command.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
regular polygon colors/.style 2 args={
    append after command={%
        \pgfextra
        \foreach \i [count=\ni, remember=\ni as \lasti (initially #1)] in {#2}{
            \draw[\i] (\tikzlastnode.corner \lasti) --(\tikzlastnode.corner \ni);}
        \endpgfextra
    }
},
]
  \node[minimum size=2cm, regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=5, 
    regular polygon colors={5}{red,blue,orange,green,cyan}] (polygon) {};

  \node[minimum size=2cm, regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=7, 
    regular polygon colors={7}{red, blue, orange, green, cyan, violet, brown},
    right=of polygon] (polygon2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\foreach \i/\c in {90/red,162/blue,234/green,306/pink,378/orange}{
 \draw[\c] (\i:1cm) -- (72+\i:1cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 1:** Another option, to have a better join line:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\foreach \i/\c in {90/red,162/blue,234/green,306/pink,378/orange}{
\fill[\c] (\i:1cm) -- (72+\i:1cm) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
}
\fill[white] (90:.95cm)--(162:.95cm)--(234:.95cm)--(306:.95cm)--(378:.95cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Edit 2:** just for fun.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \r in {1,.9,...,.1}{
\pgfmathparse{30 * \r}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\percent{\pgfmathresult}
\foreach \i/\c in {90/red,162/blue,234/green,306/pink,378/orange}{
\fill[\c!\percent] (\i:\r cm) -- (72+\i:\r cm) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proposal that defines a style `polygon side` which can be used e.g. like `\draw[red,polygon side=2];` to draw the second side red.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[get next vertex/.code n args={2}{%
\pgfmathparse{int(1+mod(#1,5))}
\xdef#2{\pgfmathresult}},
polygon side/.style={get next vertex={#1}{\tmpnextn},
insert path={(polygon.corner #1)-- (polygon.corner \tmpnextn)}}
]
  \node[draw, dotted, minimum size=2cm, regular polygon,
  regular polygon sides=5] (polygon) {};
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {red,blue,orange,green,cyan}
  {\draw[\X,polygon side=\Y];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that as of now the number of corners (or sides) as well as the name of the object (or node), `polygon`, are hard coded. One could of course use pgfkeys to store them in some keys, and if you ask me to I'll be happy to add this to this answer.